# Order by EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброе утро!

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как можно сделать сортировку по наличию определенного значения?

Т.е., допустим, у нас есть:

1) таблица **pages** с колонками: ID, content

2) таблица **meta** с колонками: ID, page_id, key, value

Мы делаем такой запрос:

```
SELECT pages.ID FROM pages 
INNER JOIN meta ON (pages.ID = meta.page_id)
WHERE (meta.key = 'price_product' AND meta.value > 0) 
GROUP BY pages.ID
```

В итоге показываются страницы с ценой больше 0. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы показывались все элементы, но сначала чтобы показывались элементы с заполненной ценой. Также стоит отметить: у некоторых элементов может быть не заполнена цена (т.е. вообще отсутствует price_product), также у некоторых price_product = 0.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [CASE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html) в предложении ORDER BY.